# Cannot resolve keyword 'model' into field. Django filters

Tags: django, django-filter, django-2.1, django-filters

I tried to rewrite filters, written on Django 1.1 to 2.1

I have a complex model, called `Apartment` that includes a `Location` model. `Location` includes the `District` model.

So, there my models code:

```
class District(models.Model):
    district_number = models.IntegerField(_('district'))
    title = models.CharField(_('district name'), max_length=100)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('city', 'district_number',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Location(models.Model):
    apartment = models.OneToOneField(Apartment, related_name='location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coordinate_long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)
    coordinate_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(_('zip'))
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    subway_station = models.ForeignKey(SubwayStation, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    address = models.CharField(_('human readable address of apartment'), max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

and filter is

```
district = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    name="location_district",
    queryset=District.objects.all(),
)
```

At new version I changed `name` to `to_field_name`.

When I tried to launch, this drop an error - `Cannot resolve keyword 'district' into field. Choices are: apartment_type, apartment_type_id, bedrooms_count, co_ownership, date_added, descriptions, economy_effective, economy_effective_id, energy_effective, energy_effective_id, favorite_lists, financial_info, floor, id, is_published, location, manager, manager_id, photos, plan, price, publish_type, publish_type_id, rooms, rooms_count, services, square, title, video_url`

I don't really understand how the `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` works, and how can I get the nested model `District` from `Location` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` `name` to `field_name`, that works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#to-field-name) you can see that the `to_name_field` is gonna be mapped out to a Django field in your model, hence why you're getting the error that Django cannot "resolve field `location_district`" because there's no `location_district` in your models.
Despite have never used DjangoFilters I believe that if you really need to name that field, you can point that to the `location`. Meaning that your filter would like something like:

```py
district = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    name="location",
    queryset=District.objects.all(),
)
```

Or you can try this but beware that I have no idea if it'll work

```py
district = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    name="location__district",
    queryset=District.objects.all(),
)
```

Comment: Already tried. Have an error - 'District' object has no attribute 'location'

Comment: Have you tried to drop the `name` altogether? Also, it'd be nice if you share your filter class.

Comment: Hmm I'm running out of options here. Maybe this can help but I'd assume you've gone through this as well https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-related-queryset-for-modelchoicefilter

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I already read that. I think that need to better understand the project logic.